# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I am studying through Python tutorial

Following tutorial I wrote the fibo module code

but it's not working

I used the Python interpreter through Ubuntu

The file was edited with an atom

there has had ModuleNotFoundError

I also reinstalled 'apt_pkg'

this is tracekback

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo.py'; 'fibo' is not a package
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo.py'; 'fibo' is not a package
```

this is fibo.py

```html
# Fibonacci numbers module

def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

==========================

## I added the tutorial below

A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended. Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable **name**. For instance, use your favorite text editor to create a file called fibo.py in the current directory

Comment: Have you added `__init__.py` file in the directory where the fibo.py file is there ?

Comment: No I didn't do There was no such thing in the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `import fibo.py` to import the module. You should use `import fibo` instead.